# Exception handling in wicket 6 into feedback panel

Tags: java, wicket

Is there a way how to handle all exception in wicket application in one place

I want this:

```
// I am not sure if this is right place
            this.getRequestCycleListeners().add(new AbstractRequestCycleListener() {
                @Override
                public IRequestHandler onException(RequestCycle cycle, Exception e) {

                    if (e instanceof MyException) {
// display message in feedback panel of current webPage like: getString(e.getCode())
                    }    
//redirect to some Error page 
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track:

```
getRequestCycleListeners().add(new AbstractRequestCycleListener() {
    @Override
    public IRequestHandler onException(RequestCycle cycle, Exception e) {
        MyException myE = Exceptions.findCause(e, MyException.class);
        if (myE != null) {
            IPageRequestHandler handler = cycle.find(IPageRequestHandler.class);
            if (handler != null) {
                if (handler.isPageInstanceCreated()) {
                    WebPage page = (WebPage)(handler.getPage());

                    page.error(page.getString(myE.getCode()));

                    return new RenderPageRequestHandler(new PageProvider(page));
                }
        }

        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: hm just 2 error in your code. Method getString is know just in webPage not in webApplication so it should be replaced by page.getString(). Second more and I understand why I can catch here just WicketRuntimeException see updated question

Comment: You're right, your exception will be wrapped in most cases. I've amended my answer.

Comment: ok I think it goes to the right direction but it still need some test if it cover all cases

Comment: I see, in case of an exception the faulting request handler is already removed. You can use #find() to get hold on a request handler which gives you access to the page.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `PageRequestHandlerTracker` to be able to find the IPageRequestHandler for the initially requested page.